# OK/Cancel dialog for Back Button

Tags: android, dialog

I am trying to make a dialog button that pops up when i am on the main activity and asks the user if they are sure they want to close the program.  I'm not sure what to add in the //Action for the Yes button... Is there a better way to do this?

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {



    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && event.getRepeatCount() == 0) {  
           AlertDialog.Builder alt_bld = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            alt_bld.setMessage("Are you sure you want to exit?")
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                // Action for 'Yes' Button



                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                //  Action for 'NO' Button

                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });
            AlertDialog alert = alt_bld.create();
            // Title for AlertDialog
            alert.setTitle("Exit Game?");
            // Icon for AlertDialog
            alert.setIcon(R.drawable.icon);
            alert.show();


    return true;
    }

    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Comment: calling finish() when pressed ok button can do the trick

Comment: I would suggest overriding the `onBackPressed()` function opposed to handling a specific key event.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can finish Your `Activity` for example. calling `finish()` method.

Apart from that consider using DialogFragments (if You use compatibility library) or `showDialog()` method in `Activity` - this will prevent leakage of windows.

Answer (score 1):

you can use simple finish() statement in you action of yes Button to exit from activity

and you can also override onBackPressed method for that